# Taking Keyboards inputs for matrix type variables in armadillo C++

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

I am not able to take keyboard inputs to set the values for vector or matrix type variables defined with the armadillo library. This is the code I am using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "armadillo"
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   vec mu1;
   cin>> mu1;
   return 0;
}
```

I get the following error message

> "E:\cpp\hell\mvnsamp.cpp|18|error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}' and 'arma::vec {aka arma::Col}')"

Attempts to input values one by one using cin>>mu1(i). 
I have also tried to take input as an array
and then assign the elements to mu1.

```
float arr[20]={};
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
     cin>> arr[i];
}
 mu1(0)=arr[0];
```

This gave an error in the output window

> "error:Mat::operator():index out of bounds terminate called after throwing an instance of std:: logic error what(): Mat::operator(): index out of bounds".

I have had similar issue whenever I tried an assignment that involves submatrix on the left hand side.
For eg:

```
B.row(1)=A
```

I would like to know if its possible to assign values to matrix/vector types from keyboard. Also, is there anyway to set values to a submatrix of a mat type using a simple assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors and matrices in Armadillo generally need to have a non-zero size before you can put elements into them.  You can set the size during the [construction](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) of the matrix, or using [.set_size()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#set_size), or using [.zeros()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#zeros_member).

Change your code to:

```
int main()
  {
  vec mu1(10, fill::zeros);

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
    double tmp;

    cin >> tmp; 

    mu1(i) = tmp;
    }

  mu1.print("mu1:");

  return 0;
  }
```

Note that using `cin` is generally bad from a user interface point of view. Instead, you may want to store all the matrix or vector values in a text file, and then load the text file.  For example, let's say we have a text file called `A.txt`, containing:

```
0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
```

You can then load the file in Armadillo using:

```
mat A;
A.load("A.txt");
```